# var attribute of p:datatable is null in header facet

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

i have datatable like this :

```
  <p:dataTable value="#{noteMB.noteList}" var="noteItem" id="noteListTable" 
        rowKey="#{noteItem.hashCode()}" selectionMode="single"  selection="#noteMB.selectedNote}" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="top"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

    <p:column width="300">
       <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{noteItem.name == 'blabla' ? 'true' : 'false' }"  />
       </f:facet> 
            <h:outputText value="#{noteItem.code}"  />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

my question: why noteItem is null in facet name="header" area ?
when i run this code header(noteItem.name) is false and column value(noteItem.code) has a value.

Comment: actually noteItem is null

Comment: well that probably cause its being processed before the table itself is being generated, its for the header data so you can't expect it to be able to access the list elements....

Answer (score 2):

noteItem is your var entry.

`var="noteItem"`

This var attribute is suppose to hold the variable item for each row of the `dataTable`.
var will iterate through every item in your `noteList`.

And as said by Daniel, during `h:facet` tag, creating rows is not even started. It is the main header of each column, where there is actually no datatable row.
Hence you get the null value there.

In short, you cannot access the object given by var attribute in facets.
Because **facets are row independent**.